# How can I resolve Homebrew openssl conflicts?

Tags: apache, openssl, homebrew

I am on High Sierra 10.13.6 and I recently ran into an issue with my Homebrew environment for local dev work. I can't seem to figure out what is the problem. Any Composer or Drush commands will give this

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I restarted my computer and when I try to start apachectl; I get

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 179 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.12_23/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.12_23/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.12_23/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so\n  Reason: image not found
```

I think this is because the path is looking for openssl, but in the Brew list, I don't have openssl anymore, it is now openssl@1.1

Bash profile has the following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

$which openssl returns

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl
```

What can I do to resolve this? Maybe I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case anyone runs into this. I managed to fix this myself.

First I commented out the following line in my usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.12_23/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Next I ran

```
$brew install php@7.3
```

I added the following lines to .bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
```

Then added the following line to usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule php7_module         /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.13/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Then I restarted my computer then ran

```
$brew services start php@7.3
$brew services restart httpd
$sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Then I had some sql connection issues.

```
$brew upgrade mariadb 
$brew services restart mariadb
$brew services restart httpd
$sudo apachectl -k restart
```

And everything came together. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If that helps somebody else not willing to reinstall PHP:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```